# Inclusion of slf4j in classpath not being picked up when program is run

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, slf4j

I have been unsuccessfully trying to include `slf4j` in a project. I've added `slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar` and `slf4j-jdk14-1.7.32.jar` into the classpath but no matter what I've tried I end up with a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory`.

The initial part of the error is

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload$WebAppClassLoaderExtension.findClass(JettyLauncher.java:354)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:366)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
    ...
```

(happy to include more if it would be helpful but the compiler cuts it off at that point)

The project is in Eclipse and I've tried

- putting the libraries at the beginning of the class path
- putting them at the end
- turning Eclipse off and on
- rebuilding the project
- using different versions

Nothing seems to work.

However, oddly, with the exact same collection of libraries it works fine in JUnit tests I've written.

This morning a coworker found that adding the pair of `slf4j` libraries to `war/WEB-INF/lib` got things working, but this isn't a workable long term solution.

I'm hoping someone out there has some bright ideas!

Edit:
Made some more progress. From [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/google-web-toolkit@googlegroups.com/msg14754.html) needed to add

```
<Set name="systemClasses">
    <Array type="java.lang.String">
        <!-- we from jetty WebAppContext source code ...-->
        <Item>java.</Item>
        <Item>javax.servlet.</Item>
        <Item>javax.xml.</Item>
        <Item>org.mortbay.</Item>
        <Item>org.xml.</Item>
        <Item>org.w3c.</Item>
        <Item>org.apache.commons.logging.</Item>
        <Item>org.apache.log4j.</Item>
        <!-- and ... added slf4j -->
        <Item>org.slf4j.</Item>
    </Array>
</Set>
```

to `jetty-web.xml`. Now need to find out what needs to change in deploy script.

Comment: The long-term solution is to use Maven or Gradle to manage your dependencies, and perhaps even to ditch legacy container setups in favor of a modern managed container such as provided by Spring Boot or Micronaut.

Comment: As @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- says, build your war with maven. (and that error message comes from the jvm, not the compiler)

Comment: *Why* isn't that a workable long term solution?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- yep :( hopefully someday we'll be given the resources to make a change like that!

Comment: @nitind: because of how we build and deploy things I think. yay tech debt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

Add the following 'systemClasses' set to the jetty-web.xml

```xml
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    ...
    <Set name="systemClasses">
         <Array type="java.lang.String">

             <!-- we copied these paths from jetty WebAppContext  source code ...-->
             <Item>java.</Item>
             <Item>javax.servlet.</Item>
             <Item>javax.xml.</Item>
             <Item>org.mortbay.</Item>
             <Item>org.xml.</Item>
             <Item>org.w3c.</Item>
             <Item>org.apache.commons.logging.</Item>
             <Item>org.apache.log4j.</Item>

             <!-- and ... added slf4j -->
             <Item>org.slf4j.</Item>

             <!-- we must promote slf4j to system classes, otherwise gwt
                  hosted mode will not allow loading them due to a policy
                  that don't allow server classes to be loaded from the
                  outside world (see gwt JettyLauncher source code). -->

         </Array>
    </Set>
</Configure>
```

As found in this message board from 2009: https://www.mail-archive.com/google-web-toolkit@googlegroups.com/msg14754.html

### How we found the solution:

While stepping through `JettyLauncher.WebAppContextWithReload.WebAppClassLoaderExtension.findClass(String name)` showed that on first load, most `super.findClass(name)` threw a `ClassNotFoundException`, then as they passed `isServerPath` they got down to using the `systemClassLoader` to load them from .jar files. Now the `systemClassLoader` has parent type `URLClassLoader` which has a field `ucp` (`URLClassPath`) that has a list (under `path`) of all the .jar files that it can load classes from. Taking a look in here, the slf4j jars indeed existed, but for some reason `isServerPath` was returning true. This is *finally* what led to finding the solution above.